# Python Script to Search PirateBay

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I've written a very basic Python 3 script to search ThePirateBay. Since the tracker doesn't have an API, I had to parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup. I'd like to get some reviews, I'm pretty sure the code is crap, so fire away. I'm also interested in projects I could read to improve my Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from urllib.parse import quote
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from constants import *
import re
import webbrowser


class Torrent:
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s / %s) (%s) (%s) (%d SE / %d LE) %s" % (self.category,
                                                           self.subcategory,
                                                           self.size,
                                                           self.date,
                                                           self.seeders,
                                                           self.leeches,
                                                           self.name)

    def download(self):
        webbrowser.open(self.magnet, autoraise=False)


def search(keywords, categories=[ALL, ], order=SEED_DESC):
    url = '%s/search/%s/0/%d/%s' % (TPB_DOMAIN, quote(keywords), order,
                                    ','.join([str(x) for x in categories]))
    return parse(url)


def parse(url):
    META_REGEX_FORMAT = "Uploaded (.*), Size (.*), ULed by (.*)"
    UNICODE_BLANK = '\xa0'
    BLANK = ' '
    ROWS = 'tr'
    DATA = 'td'

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())
    torrents = []

    for result in soup.find_all(ROWS)[1:]:
        torrent = Torrent()
        data = result.find_all(DATA)

        a = data[0].find_all('a')
        torrent.category = a[0].string
        torrent.subcategory = a[1].string

        a = data[1].find_all('a')
        torrent.link = a[0]['href']
        torrent.name = a[0].string
        torrent.magnet = a[1]['href']

        torrent.user = data[1].font.a
        if torrent.user is not None:
            torrent.user = torrent.user.text
        else:
            torrent.user = data[1].font.i.text

        pattern = re.compile(META_REGEX_FORMAT)
        match = pattern.match(data[1].font.text)

        torrent.date = match.group(1).replace(UNICODE_BLANK, BLANK)
        torrent.size = match.group(2).replace(UNICODE_BLANK, BLANK)

        torrent.seeders = int(data[2].text)
        torrent.leeches = int(data[3].text)

        torrents.append(torrent)
    return torrents


def get_query():
    text = input("Search: ")
    pattern = re.compile('"(.+)" \-(.*) \-(.*)')
    m = pattern.match(text)

    cat = []
    for x in m.group(2).upper().split(','):
        try:
            cat.append(globals()[x])
        except KeyError:
            pass

    try:
        order = globals()[m.group(3).upper()]
    except KeyError:
        order = SEED_DESC

    return m.group(1), cat, order


def search_engine():
    try:
        while True:
                kw, cat, order = get_query()

                i = 0
                results = search(kw, cat, order)
                for result in results:
                    i += 1
                    print("[%2d] %s" % (i, result))

                i = int(input('Torrent: '))
                if i > 0:
                    results[i - 1].download()
    except EOFError:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_engine()
```

**constants.py**

```
"""
CATEGORIES
"""
ALL = 0

AUDIO = 100
MUSIC = 101
AUDIO_BOOKS = 102
SOUND_CLIPS = 103
FLAC = 104
AUDIO_OTHER = 199

VIDEO = 200
MOVIES = 201
MOVIES_DVDR = 202
MUSIC_VIDEOS = 203
MOVIE_CLIPS = 204
TV_SHOWS = 205
HANDHELD = 206
HDMOVIES = 207
HDTV = 208
VIDEO_OTHER = 299

APPS = 300
WINDOWS = 301
APPS_MAC = 302
UNIX = 303
HANDHELD = 304
APPS_IOS = 305
APPS_ANDROID = 306
APPS_OTHER = 399

GAMES = 400
PC = 401
GAMES_MAC = 402
PSX = 403
XBOX360 = 404
WII = 405
HANDHELD = 406
GAMES_IOS = 407
GAMES_ANDROID = 408
GAMES_OTHER = 499

OTHER = 600
EBOOKS = 601
COMICS = 602
PICTURES = 603
COVERS = 604
PHYSIBLES = 605

"""
ORDER
"""
NAME_DESC = 1
NAME_ASC = 2
DATE_DESC = 3
DATE_ASC = 4
SIZE_DESC = 5
SIZE_ASC = 6
SEED_DESC = 7
SEED_ASC = 8
LEEC_DESC = 9
LEEC_ASC = 10
USER_DESC = 11
USER_ASC = 12

"""
MISCELLANEOUS
"""
TPB_DOMAIN = "http://thepiratebay.sx"   # Not using HTTPS because of speed
```

Comment: @200_success I did post the code, what do you mean?

Comment: I embedded the code and removed the link. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, could you post your `constants` as well?

Comment: Here they are! It's pretty basic, although I could find a way to actually generate them from the site.

Comment: If you're "pretty sure the code is crap" then this is not ready for review! You need to improve it to the point where you're pretty sure it's not crap *before* asking us to review it.

Comment: Well, I don't have ideas for improvements, but I'm sure there are things I could do more effectively.

Comment: "pretty sure the code is crap" says more about *your self-confidence as a programmer* than about your code.

Answer (score 2):

By reading the code the only thing i could 
thought to improve your code is to change this

```
def search_engine():
    try:
        pattern = re.compile('"(.+)" \-(.*) \-(.*)')
        while True:
                kw, cat, order = get_query(pattern)
```

and this one

```
def get_query(pattern):
    text = input("Search: ")
    m = pattern.match(text)
```

So you won't have to compile your regex each time

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Python expert, but I would definitely extract `parse_torrent(data)` from the `for` loop.

I wouldn't make it a `@staticmethod` on `Torrent` though,  because if you ever need to extend you code to support other trackers, `Torrent` shouldn't “know” about parsing one specific tracker's response.

So I would just place `parse_torrent` alongside other functions.

Also, your use of `globals` looks fishy: from my understanding it is [more of a debugging tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694065/458193) than something you should use in production code. It also took me a while to realize you're using it to get constant values.

This has several downsides:

- It's not evident that imported `constants` are used at all (since symbol search won't find 'em), so there's a risk someone will remove the import (with all the good intentions of course);
- Imagine there is a new category on Pirate Bay. Your code breaks. Another team member sees `globals()[x]` and now has to *guess* where to put the missing constant. Also, I'm sure the error message will be pretty confusing at first.
- It's unlikely to happen, but what if Pirate Bay adds a category called `Torrent` and you don't update your code? `globals()[x]` will return `Torrent` type, and your code will break with all the stranger symptoms.

In short, **don't use `globals()` for this**.

Instead, change

```
from constants import *

# ...

        cat.append(globals()[x])

# ...

    order = globals()[m.group(3).upper()]
```

to

```
import constants

# ...

        cat.append(constants[x])

# ...

    order = constants[m.group(3).upper()]
```

Finally, `x` and `m` are bad names for variables because they are not obvious on the first read. I understand `m` stands for “matches” but I have no idea what your regex is supposed to represent (since it's called just `pattern`). So I'm pretty much lost on what's happening inside `get_query`.

You have an extra indentation in `search_engine`.

Otherwise, the code seems fine.